# DNN 5.6 friendly urls

Tags: dotnetnuke

I am using DNN 5.6.3 and needing to redirect just one url to a page

the url is http://domain.com/schmooze and it should redirect to http://domain.com/schmooze.aspx

I have in the friendly urls part in the HOST  find:.*/schmooze.*    replace with:~/Default.aspx?TabId=258

But I get a 404 (not found) error -  Is my friendly url wrong? am I missing something else - seems this should work in the url rewriter

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this.

Open SiteUrls.config in the DNN root directory and put this in:

```
<RewriterRule>
  <LookFor>(.*)/schmooze</LookFor>
  <SendTo>~/schmooze.aspx</SendTo>
</RewriterRule>
```

You will need to make sure all IIS requests are mapped to the asp.net process. To do this, set this inside  of your web.config.

```
<modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true">
```

More info on this page for IIS:
http://www.iis.net/learn/get-started/introduction-to-iis/iis-modules-overview

If you want to start to do this through the UI of DotNetNuke. I use UrlMaster from iFinity:

http://store.dotnetnuke.com/home/product-details/ifinity-url-master-26---total-dotnetnuke-url-solution

Comment: Ventrian, - yeah I would do either the config or infinity except I don't have access to do that - good suggestion though